# How to create a new POS altcoin?

Tags: altcoin-development, proof-of-stake

I am looking to download a POS (Proof Of Stake) files to create my new altcoin, but all the instructions I found online is for the POW (Proof Of Work) and without any instructions for the blockchain. Can someone help please, or provide links?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can look into Qtum's work. I am pretty sure they use the proof of stake concept. https://github.com/qtumproject/qtum